# How to use concurrencyPolicy for GKE cron job correctly?

Tags: kubernetes

I set `concurrencyPolicy` to `Allow`, here is my `cronjob.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: gke-cron-job
spec:
  schedule: '*/1 * * * *'
  startingDeadlineSeconds: 10
  concurrencyPolicy: Allow
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 3
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            run: gke-cron-job
        spec:
          restartPolicy: Never
          containers:
            - name: gke-cron-job-solution-2
              image: docker.io/novaline/gke-cron-job-solution-2:1.3
              env:
                - name: NODE_ENV
                  value: 'production'
                - name: EMAIL_TO
                  value: 'novaline.dulin@gmail.com'
                - name: K8S_POD_NAME
                  valueFrom:
                    fieldRef:
                      fieldPath: metadata.name
              ports:
                - containerPort: 8080
                  protocol: TCP
```

After reading docs: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cronjobs

I still don't understand how to use `concurrencyPolicy`.

How can I run my cron job concurrency?

Here is the logs of cron job:

```sh
☁  nodejs-gcp [master] ⚡  kubectl logs -l run=gke-cron-job

> gke-cron-job-solution-2@1.0.2 start /app
> node ./src/index.js

config:  { ENV: 'production',
  EMAIL_TO: 'novaline.dulin@gmail.com',
  K8S_POD_NAME: 'gke-cron-job-1548660540-gmwvc',
  VERSION: '1.0.2' }
[2019-01-28T07:29:10.593Z] Start daily report
send email:  { to: 'novaline.dulin@gmail.com', text: { test: 'test data' } }

> gke-cron-job-solution-2@1.0.2 start /app
> node ./src/index.js

config:  { ENV: 'production',
  EMAIL_TO: 'novaline.dulin@gmail.com',
  K8S_POD_NAME: 'gke-cron-job-1548660600-wbl5g',
  VERSION: '1.0.2' }
[2019-01-28T07:30:11.405Z] Start daily report
send email:  { to: 'novaline.dulin@gmail.com', text: { test: 'test data' } }

> gke-cron-job-solution-2@1.0.2 start /app
> node ./src/index.js

config:  { ENV: 'production',
  EMAIL_TO: 'novaline.dulin@gmail.com',
  K8S_POD_NAME: 'gke-cron-job-1548660660-8mn4r',
  VERSION: '1.0.2' }
[2019-01-28T07:31:11.099Z] Start daily report
send email:  { to: 'novaline.dulin@gmail.com', text: { test: 'test data' } }
```

As you can see, the **timestamp** indicates that the cron job is not concurrency.

Comment: Your job spec is stating that the job should be ran every second. Looking at the logs, it seems like Kubernetes is complying. The concurrencyPolicy defines what to do when the cluster wants to start a new job, but the old one is still going. From what you've posted here, it looks like things are working as intended.

Comment: @GonçaloLourenço Thanks. I want to know how can I see the concurrency effect? Is that meanings the time my cron job cost should more than the `schedule`, don't know how can I see the cron job is really concurrency or not?
Here is my demo code https://github.com/mrdulin/nodejs-gcp/tree/master/src/kubernetes-engine/cron-job/solution2, if you have time, please take a look. thanks

Comment: I think an easy way to see how this concurrency is supposed to behave is to schedule things that last for a few minutes (like a container that sleeps for 60 seconds) and have them scheduled to be ran every few seconds. With concurrency enabled, you'll see multiple jobs executing at the same time.

Comment: Your question is about Kubernetes; not GKE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you're reading the wrong documentation. CronJobs aren't a GKE-specific feature. For the full documentation on CronJob API, refer to the Kubernetes documentation: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/#concurrency-policy (quoted below).

Concurrency policy decides whether a new container can be started while the previous CronJob is still running. If you have a CronJob that runs every 5 minutes, and sometimes the Job takes 8 minutes, then you may run into a case where multiple jobs are running at a time. This policy decides what to do in that  case.

> ### Concurrency Policy
>
> The .spec.concurrencyPolicy field is also optional. It specifies how to treat concurrent executions of a job that is created by this cron job. the spec may specify only one of the following concurrency policies:
>
> - `Allow` (default): The cron job allows concurrently running jobs
> - `Forbid`: The cron job does not allow concurrent runs; if it is time for a new job run and the previous job run hasn’t finished yet, the cron job skips the new job run
> - `Replace`: If it is time for a new job run and the previous job run hasn’t finished yet, the cron job replaces the currently running job run with a new job run
>
> Note that concurrency policy only applies to the jobs created by the same cron job. If there are multiple cron jobs, their respective jobs are always allowed to run concurrently.